# How to make a stable culinary Parmesan foam

Tags: foam

I have Knox powdered gelatin, soy lecithin, and a 0.25 liter ISI whipper. I just need to make one cup of this special liquid to pour into the whipper but I do not know the ratios of cheese, water/milk, lecithin, and gelatin. I heard you also use egg whites but the more I research about this the more I'm confusing myself -.-

Im serving this in small amounts as a garnish for a lobster bisque fyi. I do not want the foam to melt into a puddle on top of the warm/hot bisque within 5ish minutes,

Someone help me out pls

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are better off with [Xanthan Gum](http://msk-ingredients.com/MolecularGastronomy/TricksoftheTrade/XanthanGum70) instead of gelatin. Xanthan gum is relatively heat stable whereas gelatin is renowned for its inability to withstand any heat above 35 °C.

- 200g parmesan grated (including rind).
- 400ml full fat milk.
- 1 tbsp
  soy lecithin.

Bring to simmer 5 min, then blend and pass through fine sieve. Taste for seasoning now, bare in mind you want it to be over powering at this stage.

Allow to cool and then blend in:

- another tbsp soy lecithin
- one tsp Xanthan gum.

If warming for serving **do not** boil or even simmer as this will make the foam weak.

Personally I blend and scoop the foam off the top. However I see no reason why this couldn't work in a siphon.

Regarding egg white and [Hy-foamer](http://msk-ingredients.com/Hyfoamer-1056) (the molecular cuisine equivalent to egg white, where soy lecithin is the substitute for egg yolk). These are used/useful in fat free foams such as raspberry coulis. They don't work well in fat based ones like the Parmesan foam you are attempting.